# R For loop delete range of rows from one string to a second string in a column

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I am trying to delete sequences of rows from a data frame, the sequence begins with a known string, and ends with a known string, but the content and number of the intervening rows is unknown. I would like to iterate this over the entire data frame.

For example, if the data frame is as below, I would like to remove the rows from all instances of StringA to StringB (inclusive) but retain the rows which follow StringB up to the next recurrence of StringA; for the example below, that is, I would like to remove the rows containing StringA, unknownC, unknownD, unknownS, StringB, but then retain unknownK and unknownR, then continue deleting at StringA, unknownU, unknownP, StringB, but retain unknownT.

```
Column 1  Column 2 
StringA     1
unknownC    9
unknownD   11
unknownS    5
StringB    7
unknownK    6
unknownR    1
StringA    76
unknownU    2
unknownP   41
StringB    3
unknownT    9
```

I tried `df2 <- df[1:which(df[,1]=="StringA")-1,]`, which is not correct but am at a loss as what other approach to try. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Is it known for certain that stringA is always paired with a subsequent stringB? Is it also known for certain that strings A and B always alternate (e,g. Never A...A...B)?

Comment: Yes, it is. It will always be A...B, and never A..A...B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this, by constructing the index to be removed using the `Map` function:

```
indexToRemove <- unlist(Map(`:`, which(df$`Column 1` == "StringA"), 
                                 which(df$`Column 1` == "StringB")))

df[-indexToRemove, ]
   Column 1 Column 2
6  unknownK        6
7  unknownR        1
12 unknownT        9
```

**Data**:

```
structure(list(`Column 1` = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 
7L, 1L, 10L, 6L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("StringA", "StringB", "unknownC", 
"unknownD", "unknownK", "unknownP", "unknownR", "unknownS", "unknownT", 
"unknownU"), class = "factor"), `Column 2` = c(1L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 1L, 76L, 2L, 41L, 3L, 9L)), .Names = c("Column 1", "Column 2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Hmm I like the idea of this strategy Psidom, but I'm not sure how to avoid this warning I received when I tested the first step: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter

Comment: Spot on for me. Bravo

Comment: Not exactly sure, but if your column is something like `A...B...A...`  or `B...A...B..` then this could happen.

Comment: You were right, it started on a stringB, removed that, and your solution works beautifully! Thank you kindly :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop.  Although this will be slower than the vectorised solutions posted, it does have some merits in terms of being quite versatile to adapt to similar related problems, and being robust against unexpected input data.

**Notes:**

1. This method is robust against oddities in the input data - it does not depend on having always alternating and always paired, StringA...StringB pairs, nor does it assume that StringA will always occur before StringB.  Every time it encounters StringA it will start deleting rows until it encounters StringB.
2. On the down side, using this method on very large data frames could be slow, as we are growing a dataframe inside the loop (always guaranteed to slow down large operations).

**The code:**

```
keep.line <- TRUE
out.df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:NROW(my.df)) {
  if (my.df[i,]$Column1 == "StringA") keep.line <- FALSE
  if (keep.line) out.df <- rbind(out.df, my.df[i,])
  if (my.df[i,]$Column1 == "StringB") keep.line <- TRUE
}

out.df
##    Column1    Column2
##    unknownK  0.3679608
##    unknownR -0.8867749
##    unknownT  1.6277386
```

**Some data:**

```
Column1 <-c( 
"StringA" ,    
"unknownC",    
"unknownD",   
"unknownS",   
"StringB" ,   
"unknownK",   
"unknownR",   
"StringA" ,   
"unknownU",   
"unknownP",   
"StringB" ,   
"unknownT")

my.df <- data.frame(Column1, Column2 = rnorm(12), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I like this loop approach.

Answer (score 3):

Using @Psidom's data:

```
sel <- with(dat, 
  (cumsum(`Column 1`=="StringA") == cumsum(`Column 1`=="StringB"))
     &
  (!(`Column 1` %in% c("StringA","StringB")))
)
dat[sel,]

#   Column 1 Column 2
#6  unknownK        6
#7  unknownR        1
#12 unknownT        9
```

To provide some explanation - this uses `cumsum` to make two counters of how many times `"StringA"` and `"StringB"` have appeared in `Column 1`. If the numbers match, that means there has been 1 `A` and 1 corresponding `B`. As in the values marked `=` below

```
cumsum(dat$`Column 1`=="StringA")
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
cumsum(dat$`Column 1`=="StringB")
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
#            = = =       = =
```

Removing the cases where `Column 1` is `%in%` one of the target `StringA/B` strings finalises it.

Comment: This looks interesting, but is hard to follow.  Could you annotate it to explain how this works.

Comment: @dww - added explanation/